# Filling Google Chart with Ajax from a database

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get a google bar chart to get two values from a simple database and display in the graph. I can display the values from an array but when I try to get the data from database using ajax it would not get the values.(I was able to print the values in the index).

Note: Hey there I'm trying to get familiar with javascript and use google charts. I looked up almost everything that i can find still i could not solve my problem. This is my very first question to stackoverflow. Please help.

Ive got a simple database which only holds 4 values representing cashIn and cashOut of a company over 12 months.

I created a MVC web application then added the database to it. 
Here is the controller class

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DenemeDataEntities db= new DenemeDataEntities();

            List<GelirGider > gelirList = db.GelirGiders.ToList();
            Array gelirArray = db.GelirGiders.ToArray();

            //return Json(gelirList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return Json(gelirList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return View(gelirList);
        }

        public ActionResult Index2()
        {
            DenemeDataEntities db = new DenemeDataEntities();

            List<GelirGider> gelirList = db.GelirGiders.ToList();
            //Array gelirArray = db.GelirGiders.ToArray();


           return Json(gelirList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            //return View(gelirList);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Index view class

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using WebApplication2.Models;
@model List<GelirGider>



<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Ay');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Gelir');
           

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Index2',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('asdasda');
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Ay');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Gelir');
                    
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        data.addRows([ item.Ay ,item.Gelir])
                        //data.addRows(eval('[' + item.Ay + ', ' + item.Gelir ']'));
//                        data.addRows([ ['Mushrooms', 3], ]);
                    });
                    
             

                    // Set chart options
                    var options = {
                        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                        'width': 400,
                        'height': 300
                    };

                    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);

                }

            });


         
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Gelir Gider Tablosu</h1>
        <button onclick="drawChart();">bilgileri goster</button>
    </div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe this line can not take the data therefore could not put the data in to the chart. I tried some other combinations incase of an simple indentation mistake but again not worked
data.addRows([ item.Ay ,item.Gelir])

Please help. I tried to be as clear as possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: is this your real and complete code ?  because i am not seeing any jquery attached here .

Comment: This is real code but not all of it. Taken mostly from from the google charts site. what else should i add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a couple of issues in your code:

1. Using the same name for the Ajax response object and the google chart data object.
2. Google Charts Datatable.AddRows() method receives an array of arrays object and doesn't accept a single array.
3. Again you are using the newly created google chart datatable in the each statement

I've updated you Ajax code according to the previous points:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Index2',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Ay');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Gelir');
                    var arr = [];
                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        arr.push([ item.Ay ,item.Gelir]);
                    });
                    data.addRows(arr);
                    // Set chart options
                    var options = {
                        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                        'width': 400,
                        'height': 300
                    };
                    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Apperantly   data.addRows(); does not add each row one by one but adds all the rows at the same time. Getting all data to an array of arrays and then use that array while calling data.addRows() worked. Corrected other mistakes. Now Google chart gets the data from database and displays it correctly